# What are the weapons and signs in the kill feed in PUBG?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In a PUBG, the are notifications in the upper right corner that show various things:

- player kill and with what weapon "PlayerA [weapon_symbol] PlayerB",
- death from an environmental effect (fall, vehicle impact, drowning, etc.),
- death from the blue zone,
- death from the red zone.

[image: pubg kill feed]

I am particularly interested in the weapon icons. I mostly cannot recognize the DMRs and SMGs clearly.

1. What is the comprehensive list of these notification "events"?
2. Is there a setting to show the weapon names instead of icons? If yes, where do I turn it on/off?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a comprehensive list of these notification "events"?

There is [a list of all weapon icons](https://pubg.gamepedia.com/Category:UI_weapon_icons) that you can relate back to the weapons kill feed.

This doesn't include environmental or blue zone deaths but those are unique and aren't really in need of a comprehensive list.

> Is there a setting to show the weapon names instead of icons?

There's no way to change the icons into names, only the option to turn the feed on or off. (Settings > Gameplay > UI > Icon Killfeed)

Comment: The first half of this answer is link-only. Please edit relevant information into the answer body in case the page linked is changed or removed.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I know that's preferred, but it seems so tedious for me to copy and paste each individual image :(

Comment: Then this is effectively the same as the existing answer.

Comment: Give me some time to extract the info out and I'll update it :) It's gonna take some time. But this is a different answer because the other is stating that there is no comprehensive list when they do exist.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have the icon killfeed feature turned on. Here's [how](https://pubgsettings.com/turn-icon-killfeed/) you can turn it off:

To turn off the icon killfeed, simply go to your PUBG in-game settings, and under the “Gameplay” tab, under the “UI” section, you’ll see “Icon Killfeed”. Simply switch it to “OFF” and you’re good to go!

[image]

After that, your killfeed will show messages like this:

> [attacker] knocked out [victim] with [weapon]
> [attacker] killed [victim] with [weapon]

Also,

> [player] was heavily injured from [environmental damage]
> [player] died from [environmental damage]

<strike>And, no. There is no comprehensive list of kill feed notifications.</strike>

Comment: "And, no. There is no comprehensive list of kill feed notifications." - There are.

Comment: That wasn't what the question asked...

Comment: @n_plum, if you update your answer tell us about comprehensive list of the killfeed notifications I'll be much helped.